# Fetching the records which are having all time stamp columns

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am trying to fetch the records which are having all time stamp columns.

I am using the following query to fetch the products that are created between the final date and (final date - 30) days, i.e products created during the last 30 days that fall in the 'final date' range.

I have products that are created on 30-OCT-2014. For the same products, the initiated date is 12-NOV-2014. However they are not being fetched when I using the below query.

```
SELECT A.ROW_ID, 
       A.PROD_NAME 
  FROM PROD A, 
       PROD_REL B 
 WHERE A.ROW_ID = B.PAR_ROW_ID 
   AND TO_DATE(A.CREATED_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN (TO_DATE(B.FINAL_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') - 30) 
                                              AND (TO_DATE(B.FINAL_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

So, could you please let me know if I am missing something?

Here is a link to a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/233023/1) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I tried using that 

~ SELECT A.ROW_ID, 
       A.PROD_NAME 
  FROM PROD A, 
       PROD_REL B 
 WHERE A.ROW_ID = B.PAR_ROW_ID 
   AND A.CREATED_DT BETWEEN (B.FINAL_DATE - 30) 
AND B.FINAL_DATE; ~

It threw me Unknown Command for (B.FINAL_DATE - 30)

Comment: Would be helpful if you provided structure of your table(s) with data types for each column, and sample of data in that(those) table(s). Otherwise it's near to impossible to provide a however helpful answer without knowing what you store in those tables and how it being stored.

Comment: I hope there is no confusion between months versus days: 12-NOV-2014 could this be December 11, 2014?

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov: I provided the details here
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/233023/1

Comment: [Here we go](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/233023/6). You store your "dates" as, well, dates, so there is no need for `to_date()` function.

Comment: Cool, thank you. I think I made some syntax mistake while removing the 'to_date' function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data types are all dates, there is no need to use `to_date`.  It's harmful, in fact, since `to_date` doesn't take a `date` as a parameter.  Oracle has to do an implicit conversion from a date to a string, using your session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` which gets passed in to `to_date` and converted back to a date using the explicit format mask you specified.  If the two conversions aren't using the same format mask, bad things happen.

Your `WHERE` clause just needs to be

```
AND a.created_dt BETWEEN b.final_date - 30 
                     AND b.final_date
```

If I make that change, [your SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/233023/8) returns two rows

Answer (score 1):

… or just fix your format string `TO_DATE(A.CREATED,'DD-MON-YYYY')`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/233023/12/0)

Storing dates as `DATE`, is , of course, always a good starting point.